# Make scrollbar invisible in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, scrollbar, progressive-web-apps

I want to hide the scrollbar, without disabling scrolling

I used this rule in CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

I've tried also with :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

From PC, it works correctly, on mobile, regardless of the browser, I've tried both with Safari and Chrome, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* You can adjust your break point on the width to say when you want it visible */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
  }
  body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}

.test {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='test'>
    This div has a height of 1000px, you can scroll and the scrollbar is hidden.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: no, sia su cellulare che su tablet, si vede ancora la barra di scorrimento

Comment: luego cambie el ancho para que funcione en consecuencia...

Comment: Si hace clic en "Run Snippet", puede ver que la barra de desplazamiento está oculta y aún puede desplazarse.

Comment: Yes, but if you try on mobile or also on tablet, doesn’t work, there’s always a scrollbar, I think that’s the scrollbar of the device

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the above answer by KnightTheLion, for anyone who finds this question and uses [LESS](https://lesscss.org/), you can use mixins for convinience:

```
// LESS media query mixin template

@screen-phone: 767px;
@screen-tablet: 922px;
@screen-desktop: 1200px;

.media-phone(@rules) {
  @media screen and (max-width: @screen-phone) {
    @rules();
  }
}

.media-tablet(@rules) {
  @media screen and (min-width: (@screen-phone + 1px)) and (max-width: (@screen-desktop - 1px)) {
    @rules();
  }
}

.media-desktop(@rules) {
  @media screen and (min-width: @screen-desktop) {
    @rules();
  }
}

.media-custom-max(@width, @rules) {
  @media screen and (max-width: @width) {
    @rules();
  }
}

.media-custom-min(@width, @rules) {
  @media screen and (min-width: @width) {
    @rules();
  }
}

// gt=greater than
.media-gt-phone(@rules) {
  @media (min-width: (@screen-phone + 1px)) {
    @rules();
  }
}

.media-gt-tablet(@rules) {
  @media (min-width: (@screen-tablet + 1px)) {
    @rules();
  }
}
```

Here's an example in usage:

```
body {
  .media-phone ({
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
  });

}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  .media-phone ({
  display: none;
  });
}
```

You can always add more mixins and edit existing ones to account for wider screens and more.